# Can I enter Germany any time during my D visa validity?

Tags: regulations, schengen-visas

I got a German national D visa valid from 25-April-2017 to 30-Sep-2017.

It's now 15-Aug-2017.

Is it okay for me to go to Germany for the remaining validity time of my visa?

Comment: The answer is "yes, all other things being equal", so your premise at the landing interview will be taken into account and weighed in. Otherwise, fine.